# Creating multiple variables in Pharo gives me a "variable or expression expected" error

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm confused about why this code seems to work fine in isolation, but I get an error when I put it all together.

The following snippet prints **'Hello World!'** when printed:

```
| blah |
blah := 'Hello '.
blah, 'World!'.
```

But the following code block gives me the error **Variable or expression expected**

```
| blah |
blah := 'Hello '.
blah, 'World!'.
| blah2 |
blah2 := 'World!'.
blah, blah2.
```

Could someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

variable declarations are only allowed at the beginning of a block or method:

```
| blah blah2 |
blah := 'Hello '.
blah, 'World!'.

blah2 := 'World!'.
blah, blah2.
```

Comment: Please note that in the playground (or workspace) there is no need to declare temporaries. Just assign expressions to them and the workspace will automatically create the bindings.

Comment: oh, i hadn't realized. indeed. i updated the answer.